# mongodb - combine $addField with $exists

Tags: mongodb

I have something like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $match: {...} },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "assignee.fullName": { "$concat": ["$assignee.firstName", " ", "$assignee.lastName"] }
        }
    }
)
```

The problem is that for documents that don't have an 'assignee' property, the $addFields adds this:

```
assignee: {fullName: null}
```

So I'm looking for a way to only add the field if it exists, otherwise add:

```
assignee: null
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BifIupFt8if

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using concat, it will always provide the new field. So what you can do is, with your code, you can check a condition

```
{
    $addFields: {
      assignee: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$assignee.fullName",
              null
            ]
          },
          null,
          "$assignee"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7sJY_zb-gCC)**